# No most general unifier?

Tags: logic, unification

I have the task to find a most general unifier of these 2 terms:

```
f(x, f(g(x),y))
f(g(y), f(g(z),z))
```

I applied the unification algorithm until almost everything was dissolved and I got to this point:

```
g(z) = z
```

Is this right? My idea was, that there is no MGU, because replacing `z` with `g(z)` would mean we get something like this:

```
g(g(z)) = g(z)
```

Is this correct or did I mess up something?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what this 'unification algorithm' is, but I guess the answer is $t(x,y,z)=f(x, f(g(y), z))$ and notice that the first term is $t(x,x,y)$ and the second term is $t(g(y),z,z)$.

Comment: IMO, you are right; if we try to unify them starting with subst $[ g(y) \rightarrow x]$ we get $f(g(y), f(g(g(y)), y))$ from the 1st term. Now we have: $f(g(y), f(g(g(y)), y))$ and $f(g(y), f(g(z),z))$ and we are force to apply subst $[ g(y) \rightarrow z]$ to get $f(g(y), f(g(g(y)), y))$ and $f(g(y), f(g(g(y)),g(y)))$ and so on, without end.